# Is there a way to click at coordinates off-screen using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to click at coordinates off-screen using Selenium.  Everything I've found has said to scroll to the element/coordinates.  **However, I cannot scroll.  The page fits within a single screen.**

I've tried the following, but it gives me an error.

**Code:**

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
a.moveByOffset(10000, 10000).click().perform();
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds: viewport size: 1680, 896
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=100.0.1185.29)
Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-28HQ274', ip: '10.0.0.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [1732248391f4756fc95c00a6d0f737c0, actions {actions=[org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Sequence@61904d24]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: msedge, browserVersion: 100.0.1185.29, javascriptEnabled: true, ms:edgeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54306}, msedge: {msedgedriverVersion: 100.0.1185.29 (1feddedadb21..., userDataDir: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local...}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:54306/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 100.0.1185.29, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 1732248391f4756fc95c00a6d0f737c0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:627)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:617)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:573)
    at kingrabb.it.seleniumtest.Main.lambda$new$0(Main.java:40)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Line 40 in my Main.java (as mentioned in the error) is:

```
a.moveByOffset(10000, 10000).click().perform();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you expect by click off screen?

Comment: As the error message showed, such a parameter (`10000`) is already out of range, the your current viewport size is only `1680 * 896`. You can try maximizing the window and adjusting this parameter, but you still can't get it out of the viewport size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you cannot click out of the viewport.

However, you can modify the browser size to take up your entire screen:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1680, 896));
```

The window can also be maximised by:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

This expands the space that you can click and is (as far as I'm aware) the best solution due to Selenium's current capabilities.